# web application in stage can't connect to azure cloud, working fine in development environment

Tags: azure, timeout, stage

While working on one of my project, I am uploading documents from our content server(as we are using documentum) to azure cloud. As we want to save some space on our content server. I have written below code to upload my zipped files on azure cloud. I development environment it is working fine but in stage environment it is throwing timeout errors, it shows 
"An unknown failure occurred : Connection timed out: connect"

Also when I try to download the file(it works fine in development environment), but in stage it shows "An error occurred while enumerating the result". It doesn't throw any exception nor any error is there.

My code is :

```
if (Boolean.parseBoolean(azureCloudUseDefaultContainer)) {
    container = client.getContainerReference(azureCloudDefaultContainer);
    }else {
        container = client.getContainerReference(DEFAULT_CONTAINER);
    }
            container.createIfNotExists();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(assetName);

    BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
    blobRequestOptions.setTimeoutIntervalInMs(10000);
    blobRequestOptions.setRetryPolicyFactory(new RetryLinearRetry(3000,3));
    //blob.upload(new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
    // If blob already exist on cloud it means asset was uploaded in past, so no need to upload it again
    // to avoid duplicate blobs on cloud
        if(!blob.exists()){
               blob.upload(new FileInputStream(file), file.length(), null, blobRequestOptions, null);
            }
```

Is this any configuration issue or network problem. what is your opinion

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSL certificate (it is not clearly stated in your question so it is only my assumption) then you must also configure it for staging slot. Have you seen [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing) about configuring deployment slots? Some settings are not swapped when using slotsin App Service.

Settings that are swapped:

```
General settings - such as framework version, 32/64-bit, Web sockets
App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
Connection strings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
Handler mappings
Monitoring and diagnostic settings
WebJobs content
```

Settings that are not swapped:

```
Publishing endpoints
Custom Domain Names
SSL certificates and bindings
Scale settings
WebJobs schedulers
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. I have updated protocol from http to https, now it is working fine